# Can i with Kotlin simulate click on physical button on Android device?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Can i with Kotlin simulate click on physical button on device?
.performClick? 
I need simulate click on power button (KEYCODE_POWER https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent)
Thank you

Comment: what you want to try on power button click ?

Comment: For lock device screen